Manage WebSocket Reconnection in Redux Saga using TypeScript
How can I adjust the code below of my saga to automatically create a new WebSocket connection when a WebSocket connection is closed and also cancel the previous setupWebSocket() saga worker?
I am learning React and Redux Saga, and it seems like a difficult topic, especially with TypeScript and its many different types.
(https://devbytes.co.in/news/reduxexplainer-what-are-common-issues-with-websocket-events-in-sagas)
import {takeEvery, fork, put, all, takeLatest} from "redux-saga/effects";
import { eventChannel } from "redux-saga";

function* onMessage(event: any) {
  const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
  // Send message to reducer
  yield put({type: "UPDATE_MESSAGES", payload: message })
}

function* onCloseWebSocket(socket: any, event: any): any {
  console.log('Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 1 second.', event);
}

function* setupWebSocket() {
  var socket : any;
    try {
      socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws/socket-server/');

      const messageChannel = eventChannel((emitter) => {
        socket.addEventListener("message", emitter);
        return () => socket.removeEventListener("message", emitter);
      });

      const closeChannel = eventChannel((emitter) => {
        socket.addEventListener("close", emitter);
        return () => socket.removeEventListener("close", emitter);
      });

      yield takeEvery(messageChannel, onMessage)
      yield takeEvery(closeChannel, onCloseWebSocket, socket)
      yield takeLatest("ON_SEND_MESSAGE", (action: any) => socket.send(JSON.stringify(action.payload)));

    } catch (error) {
      // TODO
    }
}

function* messagesSaga(): Generator {
  yield all([
    fork(setupWebSocket)
  ]);
}

export default messagesSaga;

Please feel free to ask for context, and thanks to all those trying to answer this. <3
